# One problem on characteristic function and convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_n =>^d X, a_n -> a $ and $b_n -> b$ then I have to prove that $a_nX_n +b_n =>^d aX+b$ using characteristic functions.

Soln: So enough to prove that $E[e^{it(a_nX_n +b_n)}]- > E[e^{it(aX+b)}]$ for all $t$. From Skorohods theorem, we know that there exists random variables $X_n'^~$ and $X'$ such that $X_n'$  and $X'$ have the same distribution as $X_n$ and $X$ respectively and $X_n'(\omega) -> X'(\omega)$. Hence, $E[e^{it(a_nX_n +b_n)}] = E[e^{it(a_nX_n' +b_n)}] -> E[e^{it(aX'+b)}]=E[e^{it(aX+b)}]$.

$E[e^{it(a_nX_n' +b_n)}] -> E[e^{it(aX'+b)}]$. This is due to $BCT$.

Is this argument correct ?

Comment: is it that $DCT/BCT$ work for only real valued functions ?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct, but the usage of the characteristic functions seems rather artifical to me. You have shown that, by the Skorohod theorem, there exist random variables $X_n' \sim X_n$ and $X' \sim X$ such that $X_n' \to X'$ a.s. and, therefore, $a_n X_n' +b_n \to a X'+b$ a.s. Now Skorohod's theorem automatically yields $a_n X_n + b_n \stackrel{d}{\to} aX+b$, so you don't have to consider any characteristic functions.

Actually, one can show that $a_n X_n + b_n \stackrel{d}{\to} aX+b$ without applying the Skorohod theorem. The proof is based on the fact that the characteristic functions do not only convergence pointwise, but locally uniformly. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317706/x-n-stackreld-to-x-c-n-to-c-implies-c-n-cdot-x-n-stackreld-to) for more details.

(And, let me finally remark that the dominated convergence works fine for complex-valued functions; simply consider the real and imaginary part separtely.)