# Show that if $Z_{n}-X_{n}$ converges weakly to $0$ and $Z_{n}$ converges weakly to $Z$, then $X_{n}$ converges weakly to $Z$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

This post is about my extended thought after I did the (depending on the editions) **Exercise 2.2.10** or **Exercise 2.2.13** of **Durrett**.

The exercise itself states as follow:

> Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $\{Y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $X$ be random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $X_{n}\Rightarrow X$ and $Y_{n}\Rightarrow c$.
>
> Show that Deduce that $X_{n}+Y_{n}\Rightarrow X+c$.

Then, he commented that

> If $X_{n}\Rightarrow Z$ and $Z_{n}-X_{n}\Rightarrow 0$, then $Z_{n}\Rightarrow Z.$

I proved this exercise and convinced myself of this comment, since if $X_{n}\Rightarrow Z$, and $Z_{n}-X_{n}\Rightarrow 0$. Then by the exercise, it follows immediately that $$Z_{n}=X_{n}+(Z_{n}-X_{n})\Rightarrow Z+0=Z.$$

However, I am thinking about if this is sufficient and necessary, i.e.

> If $Z_{n}-X_{n}\Rightarrow 0$, then $Z_{n}\Rightarrow Z$ if and only if $X_{n}\Rightarrow Z.$

The comment in Durret is about $(\Leftarrow)$, but I don't know how to show the converse.

If we want to use the same techniques, we will have $$Z_{n}+(Z_{n}-X_{n})\Rightarrow Z,$$ but not the RHS cannot give us $X_{n}$.

Therefore, I think this breaks down the question to whether $Z_{n}-X_{n}\Rightarrow 0$ implying $X_{n}-Z_{n}\Rightarrow 0$ is true.

I tried to show it but I failed.

Any idea?

**By the way, $(\Rightarrow)$ is weak convergence.**

Comment: What type of convergence does $\Rightarrow$ denote? Convergence in distribution?

Comment: @Math1000 yes, weak convergence.

Comment: $Y_n \to 0$ in distribution implies $-Y_n \to 0$ in distribution, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317706/36150) (for an actually more general result). Apply this for $Y_n =Z_n-X_n$

Comment: @saz hi, I don't see how I can apply this post to prove your claim..

Comment: @saz is there any more direct proof of $Y_{n}\Rightarrow 0$ implies $-Y_{n}\Rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Well, yes. The result which I linked is more general than the one which you need.

Comment: @saz yes but I think if I only prove the simpler one, the proof will be also simpler..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $Y_n := Z_n-X_n \to 0$ in distribution implies $-Y_n = X_n-Z_n \to 0$ in distribution. In order to prove this, recall that  a sequence $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in distribution to a random variable $Y$ if, and only if,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}f(Y_n) = \mathbb{E}f(Y)$$

for any bounded continuous function $f$.

Take $f$ bounded and continuous. If we set $g(x) := f(-x)$ then

$$\mathbb{E}f(-Y_n) = \mathbb{E}g(Y_n).$$

Since $g$ is bounded and continuous, it follows from $Y_n \to 0$ in distribution that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}f(-Y_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}g(Y_n) = g(0) = f(0).$$

This shows that $-Y_n \to 0$ in distribution.

Comment: wow. amazing. thank you!